# Error produced when trying to solve ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

```
NDSolve[{x0'[t] == -x0[t]*s*x1^2 + s*x1^2, x1'[t] == x1*s*x1^2, 
  x2'[t] == -x2[t]*s*x1^2, x0[0] == x1[0] == x2[0] == 1}, {x0, x1, 
  x2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

All dependent variables must depend explicitly on `t`, and all symbols must be defined.  For instance,

```
sol = NDSolve[{x0'[t] == -x0[t]*s*x1[t]^2 + s*x1[t]^2, 
    x1'[t] == x1[t]*s*x1[t]^2, x2'[t] == -x2[t]*s*x1[t]^2, 
    x0[0] == x1[0] == x2[0] == 1} /. s -> 1/2, {x0, x1, x2}, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[{x0[t], x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x0,x1,x2"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, and certainly more informatively, the equations can be solved with `DSolve`

```
First@DSolve[{x0'[t] == -x0[t]*s*x1[t]^2 + s*x1[t]^2, 
    x1'[t] == x1[t]*s*x1[t]^2, x2'[t] == -x2[t]*s*x1[t]^2, 
    x0[0] == x1[0] == x2[0] == 1} , {x0[t], x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
(* {x1[t] -> 1/Sqrt[1 - 2 s t], x0[t] -> 1, x2[t] -> Sqrt[1 - 2 s t]} *)
```

Comment: When i run, what you did, it shows me that The function x1 appears with no arguments. >>

Comment: @user36338  Whether or not the answer from `NDSolve` is shown with arguments, the dependent variables given to `NDSolve` must have the proper arguments, or `NDSolve` will not run.

Comment: if i follow what you did, will i be able to get to the same result ?

Comment: For `NDSolve`, yes.  For `DSolve`, I cleaned up the answer slightly.

Comment: sol = NDSolve[{x0'[t] == -x0[t]*s*x1[t]^2 + s*x1[t]^2, 
    x1'[t] == x1[t]*s*x1[t]^2, x2'[t] == -x2[t]*s*x1[t]^2, 
    x0[0] == x1[0] == x2[0] == 1} /. s -> 1/2, {x0, x1, x2}, {t, 0, 
   1}] I am sorry for bothering you again. When i run this one, it will show this  NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function x1 appears with no arguments. >>

Comment: @user36338  This is not the equation in my answer.  Copy it instead of trying to type it.

Comment: I copied and put in mathematica. i am sure that there's not mistake. i went over in details. i do not know when i pasted in the comment section, it does not appear clear. i am still getting the same message (The function x1 appears with no arguments.)

Comment: It works fine, when I copy and run the code in my answer, except that it becomes stiff at `t = 1`, which you can safely ignore.  (Alternatively, set `s` to any positive value smaller than `1/2` to eliminate the stiffness issue, if you wish.)  I definitely do not receive the error you do. I suggest that you restart Mathematica, copy the code into a fresh notebook, and try again.